# FIle upload to web service, in Objective C not working

Tags: objective-c, file-upload

I need some extra set of eyes.
the below code is not firing at all:

```
NSString *apiUrl = @"<WEB SERVICE URL>";
NSString *theFileName = [file_path lastPathComponent];

NSArray *parameters = @[ @{ @"name": @"file", @"fileName": theFileName, @"file_path" : file_path } ];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file_path];
NSError *error;
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if (param[@"fileName"]) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",param[@"name"] , param[@"fileName"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
         [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    } else {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",param[@"name"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", param[@"value"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *postData = body;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiUrl]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Ive been looking at this all day, and can't seem to find, what I'm missing.

Basically I'm trying to rewrite my old file upload, that uses sendSynchronousRequest, witch works, but is deprecated.

Old working code.

```
    NSString * urlString = @"<WEB SERVICE URL>";
        NSString *theFileName = [path lastPathComponent];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", theFileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // close form
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];


        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];


        //NSLog(@"File posted");
        return dict;
    }else{
       // NSLog(@"upload failed");
    }
```

Been searching SO for pointers, but haven't managed to come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've forgotten to set the content type header:

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

Also, move this:

```
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

to the end of `for` block rather than outside of it, because you need this line-end for every part.

And the last note: all `Content-Disposition:` should end with two `\r\n`, so add one after `filename=\"%@\"\r\n` -> `filename=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, but the above doesn't solve the issue :) If the headers are formatted wrongly, I should get a http response error code. But nothing is returned and the function still doesn't execute, at all. Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure your function is being executed at all?

Comment: yes, function is executed 2019-09-16 14:32:27.545591+0200 file_upload[88334:1207028] I ran just fine!
Program ended with exit code: 0, but its like dataTask is never called?

Comment: I think we need a sample app in order to understand the root cause of the issue

Comment: Ok here you go, link to test app. [https://gist.github.com/jemik/bd2c4b845edab4de79e737ba53dfaa5a#file-file_upload-m]
Unfortnunally I cant provide the full flask app, but here is a snippet for the upload function
`@app.route("/fileuploader",methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def fileuploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),SAMPLE_PATH)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save( os.path.join(file_path, filename ))`

Comment: If you're really trying to call the uploadFile method from the main function, you will not succeed, because the app will be terminated right after starting. In order to test your method it'd better to create a Single View Application and test your method in the AppDelegate or in a ViewController class...

Comment: Im not :) this is just the single function, as an example. 
I can't share the entire source of the project.
Long story short. The app is monitoring a dir for changes, and when a new file is added, or an existing is modified, the file is uploaded to a analysis service, and the response is then added as a JSON object, and finally posted to an Elastic backend. So, the app really never terminates.